# NetworkX not showing the data attributes of nodes

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I am having this weird behavior with NetworkX that is not following what would be expected based on the [documentation on the Graph object](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/reference/classes.graph.html#networkx.Graph).

Here is my code:

```
In [22]: G = nx.Graph()

In [23]: G.add_node("Roasted",attr_dict={"css_color":"#454463"})

In [24]: G["Roasted"]
Out[24]: {}

In [25]: G.nodes(data=True)
Out[25]: [('Roasted', {'css_color': '#454463'})]
```

At `In [23]` I added a node with an attribute dictionary. In `In [24]`, I was simply indexing the graph `G` like I would on a dictionary and expected it to return `{'css_color':'#454463'}`but I got back an empty dictionary instead. I only get to see that dictionary if I were to call for a printout of the list of nodes with their data displayed.

In the documentation, it showed that:

```
>>> G.add_node(1, time='5pm')
>>> G.add_nodes_from([3], time='2pm')
>>> G.node[1]
{'time': '5pm'}
```

you should be able to obtain the dictionary simply by indexing on the node name itself. Why did it not work for my case?

**EDIT:** In case the problem could have been that I used a string instead of an int for the node name, I tried this:

```
In [29]: G.add_node(1,attr_dict={"css_color":"#454463"})

In [30]: G[1]
Out[30]: {}
```

And the problem still persists! Could this be a bug???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation that `G["Roasted"]` should give the attributes of the node `"Roasted"` is the source of the error.  In fact `G["Roasted"]` gives information about the neighbors of `"Roasted"`.  The fact that it is an empty dictionary represents the fact that you have not assigned any neighbors to `"Roasted"`.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G[1]
>{2: {}}
```

What you need to use is `G.node["Roasted"]` rather than `G["Roasted"]`.

Comment: Oh gosh! I can't believe I made such a silly mistake! Thank you so much!